# How can I view/alter data stored using the SPPersistedDataObject class manually?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sppersistedobject

I am currently storing data using an `SPPersistedObject`.

I am transitioning from previously using a SharePoint List.  However, one benefit of the list was being able to go in and change the data manually (if needed).

I'd like to still provide this functionality either using a view ( if possible ) or possibly interacting with the data in SQL Server or SharePoint Designer ( if possible ).

Are there any other alternatives that I'm not considering ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SPPersistedObject worked well as a solution.